# Drake: any tutorial or example for nonlinear model predictive control?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, drake

I am currently learning the usage of the MIT [Drake](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake) library for optimization and would like to **formulate a nonlinear model predictive control problem**. I notice that the [pydrake examples](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/tutorials) show the methods to add nonlinear costs and constraints in a nonlinear program problem. However, I am not sure **how to integrate nonlinear (and maybe even switching) system dynamics into the optimization problem**. Are there any related examples or useful hints? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Keran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a set of "trajectory optimization" classes that make it easy to set up a MathematicalProgram for this case.  I'd recommend looking at http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/trajopt.html.

The switching case needs more care, depending on exactly how you formulate it.  I would need more details to advise.  But planning through contact is similar: http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/contact.html .